# Apache POI - Creating a cell, setting a cell-value and cell-style in a single command

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to create a cell, assign a pre-existing style to it and set the value for that cell. This can be accomplished normally by using the following 3 lines of code:

```
HSSFRow row = sheetBenefits.createRow(rowNoPB+i);
HSSFCell cell0 = row.createCell(1);
cell0.setCellStyle(style);
cell0.setCellValue(new String("Survey "+i));
```

However, the cell creation and assigning the value can be reduced to a single line as follows:

```
row.createCell(1).setCellValue(new String("Survey "+i));
```

I am not able to set the style in this line as:

```
row.createCell(1).setCellValue(new String("Survey"+i)).setCellStyle(style);
```

The error it gives me is "Cannot invoke setCellValue(String) on the primitive type void". What is the error in this case? How can I achieve all 3 objectives in a single line of code?

Answer (score 2):

The `setCellValue` method's return type is `void`, so it is not valid to put the `setCellStyle` method after calling `setCellValue`.

On the other hand, you may consider to write a static method to do the work for you.

```
public static Cell addCell(Row row, int columnIndex, CellStyle cellStyle, String value) 
{
    Cell cell = row.createCell(columnIndex);
    cell.setStyle(cellStyle); 
    cell.setValue(value);
    return cell;
}
```

To add a cell just call the static method:

```
addCell(row, 1, cellStyle, "Hell World");
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `row.createCell` returns an object of type `HSSFCell` so you can invoke a further method on it. Which you do, by invoking the method `setCellValue`.

But this method returns `void` - it doesn't return anything. So you cannot invoke further methods on it.

What's worse, you didn't store the result of `row.createCell` anywhere, so you have lost the reference that you created. You'll need to retrieve it again from the `row`, or what's better - you need to have stored it in a (local) variable in the first place.

What you are looking for is a "fluid interface", like that implemented by `StringBuilder` or other builders. However, Apache POI isn't designed with a fluid interface, so you can't do this.

You'll have to go with the first piece of code that you wrote.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!